# Is there any way to check a field against Regex as a user is typing in Velocity?

Tags: velocity, dotcms

I'm trying to get some code working in DotCMS that will check as a user types against Regex (for password validation). I already have the Regex sorted but i can't find any way to do a positive look ahead on the field as the user types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I can think to make this happen is by creating a custom field.  That way, you can make it act exactly how you would like it to act.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, i managed to add an ID to the field and check it against regex by adding a JavaScript function!